# ¿Java Como convertir un atributo String a Nominal para clasificar en Weka?

Tags: java, string

Hola tengo un programa escrito en java que realiza el proceso de clasificacion utilizando la libreria de weka 3.6 y predice a que clase pertenece un nuevo registro cuando agrego los datos el problema es que solo funciona cuando son datos numericos ya que cuando intento agregar datos string me aparece el error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value not defined for given nominal attribute!

Quisiera saber ¿Cómo puedo traducir los atributos string en nominales?

```
Instance instance = new Instance(8);

Attribute atributo = train.attribute("NumPalabras");
Attribute atributo2 = train.attribute("Texto");
Attribute atributo3 = train.attribute("valor1");
Attribute atributo4 = train.attribute("valor2");
Attribute atributo5 = train.attribute("valor3");
Attribute atributo6 = train.attribute("valor4");
Attribute atributo7 = train.attribute("ValorMasAlto");

instance.setValue(atributo, NumPalabras);
instance.setValue(atributo2, Texto);///AQUI ES DONDE SE PRENSENTA EL ERROR
instance.setValue(atributo3, valor1);
instance.setValue(atributo4, valor2);
instance.setValue(atributo5, valor3);
instance.setValue(atributo6, valor4);
instance.setValue(atributo7, ValorMasAlto);

instance.setDataset(train);
return instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

No he usado nunca esa librería así que no tengo apenas conocimiento, pero leyendo la [documentación oficial](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html) parece que para Attribute númerico debes usar un segundo parámetro en el constructor:

`Attribute(java.lang.String attributeName, boolean createStringAttribute)
Constructor for a numeric or string attribute.`

En el tuyo estás usando el simple, sin el boolean a false para decir que NO es String. Prueba con eso

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder muchas gracias tambien desconosco mucho de esta libreria pero revisare la documentacion oficial para ver si logro convertir el atributo a nominal o crearlo, saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: Hola aun no logró convertir mi atributo String a nominal ojala alguien me pueda ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho, saludos.